# Model in variable giving unexpected '::'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

So I was wondering how can we access a model which is placed in a variable

Controller :

```
use App\Models\Test;
use App\Models\Owner;
class mainController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->home = new MainHelper();
    }
```

mainHelper.php :

```
class MainHelper {
    var $test       = 'App\Models\Test';
    ...
    public static function listTesting(){
        $data = $this->test::where('icons_status', '=', 'active')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
        return $data;
    }
```

Test.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'test';
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $guarded = array('id');
    public $timestamps  = false;
}
```

But I get this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\Helpers\MainHelper.php on line 34
```

Or am I doing it wrong? I'm trying to find a way without using `use App\Model\Test`

Comment: at first look I found a typo in mainHelper.php : $data = $this->test::::where('icons_status', '=', 'active')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();  $this->test::::where must be $this->test::where, but I dont know it will work or not :)

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan fixed but it still happens

Comment: Is the error same?

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan yeah it still the same

Comment: which version php do you use?

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 19:48:22)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you want to assign a model into a variable?, Second of all, in this line:

```
var $test       = 'App\Models\Test';
```

you are assigning a String, not a Model, so obviously is not going to work as you expected.

What you can do is:

```
var $test       = new App\Models\Test;
```

and then use

```
var $test->where(....)
```

or do it in the same instruction:

```
$data = App\Models\Test::where('icons_status', '=', 'active')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$this->test::where
```

to:

```
$this->test->where
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you trying access from static method via $this, to nonstatic  field it must be something like this

```
class MainHelper
{
   public static $test = 'App\Models\Test';

    public static function listTesting()
    {
       $data = self::$test::where('icons_status', '=', 'active')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
       return $data;
    }
 }
```